# Adding Delphi 6 third party component to Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, ide, components, delphi-2010

I have a few Delphi 6 third party components which I need to add to Delphi 2010 to begin my migration. Is it possible? The interface seem a lot different and I can't seem to find a way to do this?

This help...

My components: DBGridEasy, TSerial, Varian Async32.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been mentioned this is not straightforward. But you do have options.

- Check with Vendor and get update
- if you have source you can try to update yourself.

I don't agree that it is neccesarily too complicated to upgrade. Delphi 2009 did add (finally - about a decade after it should have) very good Unicode support into the heart of delphi, but this was done down to the level of almost every built in function.

We upgraded a large (700,000 lines) project in only a couple of days.  There is info on the net on what to do, there are a number of functions you need to replace if you use them (such as any funcion with Ansi in the title).  Its worth a try at least.

If you dont have the source I'm afraid you have no choice but to contact the vendor, there is nothing you can do since the binary format for each Delphi version is differnt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure about those particular components, but it probably won't work even if you have the source for them because there were many changes between those versions, such as the string type changing.  You would be better off finding out if the vendor has updated them.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest change between Delphi 6 and Delphi 2010 is the changing of the default strings to Unicode in Delphi 2009.

I highly recommend against using any pre-Delphi 2009 component with your upgrade. They will not know about Unicode and you will run into problems.

First, you should see if the new version of Delphi already has the functionality you want built in. Many things have been upgraded over the years. You may find you don't need some of your old components at all.

For the ones you still need, try to find an upgrade, or some other similar component that is ready for Delphi 2009. There are many grids around. I am not familiar with Serial or Async programs to recommend one.

Comment: Changing components is often more work than patching existing ones for unicode. Specially if they are not big.

Answer (score 0):

This might already help you: Varian Async was acquired by TMS, the same component is now known as [TMS Async32](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/async32.asp)